# The correct class hierarchy

Tags: oop, design-patterns

In general case we have following document types:

- Document with header part (сlass DocumentHeader)
- Document with header and detail parts (сlass DocumentDetail)

Both classes are abstract and we need to inherit from them in order to realize required functionality:

- сlass DocumentHeader {}
- class DocumentDetail : DocumentHeader {}

Next, we have concrete documents:

- Consolidated order. Contains consolidated data about order (class Order)
- Detailed order. Contains consolidated data and table part with detail about ordered products (class OrderDetail)

So, we have a problem:

Detailed order should inherit functionality from consolidated order:

- class OrderDetail : Order {}

Both detailed and consolidated orders should inherit from abstract classes:

- class Order : DocumentHeader {}
- class OrderDetail : DocumentDetail {}

Please give an idea, how to realize that. Thanks!

Comment: In a language with mixin / multiple inheritance support, you can just do that. In a language with only single inheritance, you need to emulate mixins with members. I would suggest making `DocumentDetail` a separate class that's a member of `OrderDetail`, and delegating functionality to it.

Comment: I doubt very much that OrderDetail should inherit from Order. If OrderDetail is a container/document/or GUI component, then it should be compositional relationship to Order. Ie. OrderDetail contains an Order. Then you don't have to worry about multiple inheritance

Comment: I agree 100% with @OliverWatkins `OrderDetail` inheriting from `Order` makes no sense

Comment: I agree that the inheritance should be reviewed. "Favor composition over inheritance". Maybe you even need types Header and Detail instead, and have your document types use has-a relationships to them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Psuedo-ish code would be something like

```
class CDocument
{
  public:
    CDocument ( IDocumentHeader header, IDocumentDetails details ) : 
      this.header(header), this.details(details) {}

    IDocumentHeader GetHeader() { return header; }
    IDocumentDetails GetDetails() { return details; }

  private:
    IDocumentHeader header;
    IDocumentDetails details;
};
```

Not entirely sure on your Order/Order detail relationship, but you could have order as a CDocument, which contains a DocumentHeader implementation and a OrderDetail implementation of DocumentDetails.

```
class CDocumentHeader : IDocumentHeader{};

class COrderDetail : IDocumentDetail{};

void Whatever()
{
  CDocument order ( new DocumentHeader(), new OrderDetail() );
}
```